# Using AJAX to send data to FormCollection

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, formcollection

I'm trying to using FormCollection instead of a model.
I created my AJAX request:

```
myData = {
        id: '1',
        name: $("#name").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/testController/Test',
        data: JSON.stringify(myData),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            // do something
        },
        error: function (erro) {
            console.debug(erro);
        }
    });
```

My controller with FormCollection

```
[HttpGet, ValidateInput(false)]
    public JsonResult Test(FormCollection formData)
    {
        string name = formData["name"].ToString();
    }
```

However, my formData is always null. Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: Why? I want to get data not post

Comment: If you want a GET, then remove the `contentType` option and `JSON.stringify()` - its just `data: myData` (a GET has no body). And the method becomes `public JsonResult Test(int id, string name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making GET request, you are actually making this request. And you need to access the parameter by `Request['id']` & `Request['name']`.

Request URI: `/testController/Test?id={data_id}&name={data_name}`

Request Body: `<empty>`

However, if you are making POST request, you are making this request:

Request URI: `/testController/Test`

Request Body: `{"id":"data_id","name":"data_name"}`

The request body is parsed and you can access the data through `FormCollection`. That's why `FormCollection` is always null when you make GET request.